# JPA Repository many to one

Tags: spring, jpa, many-to-one

I have `Student` entity and `Course` entity. This is `@ManyToOne` relationship i.e. `Student` may attend only one course at a time, but courses may have multiple students.

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String studentId;
    private String firstName;
    private String secondName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    //@JsonIgnore
    private Course course;
@Entity
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String courseName;
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy = "course", orphanRemoval = true, targetEntity = Student.class)
private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
```

I post my data with the following json:

```
    {   
        "id": 1,
        "courseName": "course134",
        "students" : [
            {
                "id" : 1,
                "studentId": "123",
                "firstName": "John1",
                "secondName": "Name1"
                
            },
            {
                "id" : 2,
                "studentId": "1234567",
                "firstName": "John2",
                "secondName": "Name2"
                
            }
```

then, as I get courses I receive:

```json
    {
        "id": 1,
        "courseName": "course134",
        "students": []
    }
```

How to list Students attending specific course?
I made up a Query in StudentRepository

```
    @Query("SELECT s from  Student s where s.id = :courseName")
        Optional<Student> getStudentByCourseName(String courseName);
```

Still not working.

this is my Repository code:

```
    @Repository
    public interface CourseRepository extends JpaRepository<Course, Long> {
        Optional<Course> findCourseByCourseName(String courseName);
        @Query("SELECT c.students FROM Course c WHERE c.courseName = :courseName")
        Optional<Student> getStudentsByCourseName(String courseName);
    }
```

this is my Service method

```
      public Optional<Student> findStudentByCourse(String courseName){
            return courseRepository.getStudentsByCourseName(courseName);
        }
```

and finally my Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/student/course/{courseName}")
public ResponseEntity<Student> findCoursesWithStudentId(@PathVariable String courseName) {
    Optional<Student> byCourseName = studentService.findStudentByCourse(courseName);
    if (byCourseName.isPresent()) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(byCourseName.get());
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, about Cotroller code format. I  can't modify it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should query the Course table, not the Student table. Also, the query will return the list, not just one entity, so change your method's return type also...

```
@Query("SELECT c.students FROM Course c WHERE c.courseName = :courseName")
List<Student> getStudentsByCourseName(String courseName) {}
```

**edit**
You can always do it like so:

1. Excute the simple method:

```
Course findByCourseName(String courseName) {}
```

2. and then just get its Students by a simple:

```
course.getStudents();
```

Comment: I did as you say, although I receive no data output, now Postman does not indicate internal server error no more

Comment: That's weird, but I've added a simpler solution to my answer. If that doesn't work, please tell us what these methods return...

Comment: You have a REST controller, not MVC, so it wouldn't return a view, just a JSON...

Comment: Could you please give me some reference to read about it.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-normal-Spring-MVC-and-Spring-RESTful-web-service